# How to set JBOSS/JDBSC to cach the MySQL server settings?

Tags: mysql, jboss, glassfish, jdbc

Is it possible to set JBOSS/JDBC's MySQL connector to cache the server's settings so that I won't get a big bunch of "show variables" connection all the time?

I think there is a similar settings under Glassfish called CacheServerConfiguration but I was not able to find more information about that under JBOSS.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Edit: Got it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. All I had to do was to append that to the jdbc URL like this.

jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database_name?cacheServerConfiguration=true

More information is available here: http://www.yaldex.com/mysql_manual/ch23s04.html